# HTML/CSS Block not appearing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to see why the content below is not going into the box which it's inside as defined within the HTML

This is the image because I do not have enough rep yet to add it to the formatting https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3nWx.png

This is the HTML which I am using

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-title">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <h4>Server 1</h4> 
                    <span class="label label-success">Online <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess you use float on the content inside? did you clear both after that?

Comment: Do you have CSS code?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://jsbin.com/jegebiyone/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I added the clearfix class. Thanks for reminding me, Math4w.
[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) is a link to some documentation regarding the clearfix class: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

So the final code looked like this,

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-title">
                <h2>Servers</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <p class="well text-center">
                      <strong>Server 1</strong>
                      </br>
                      <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-check">Online</i></span>
                  </p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Looking at your code, I suppose you are using Twitter Bootstrap.

From you code you have the column `<div class="col-md-1">` class inside the outer column `<div class="col-md-4">`.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that bootstrap requires that you wrap a columns with a `<div class="row">` so as to clear the float.

### Option 2

You could add `clear: both;` in the class **.box-body** in your css code. It will clear the column float.

Answer (score 0):

**md_5** Hi there.  Looks like you are wanting to have the title have it's own area from the box-body.

How about something like this example.
I use some color to show each block.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydxLtuqr/)**.

```
<div class="container col-xs-6 block1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="block-title bg-primary">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body col-md-12 bg-info">               
                <h4>Server 1</h4> 
                <span class="label label-success">Online <i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]